# How to make first column in UITableView not scroll horizontally in iPhone Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiscrollview

I have made horizontally scrollable UITableView by adding a table view to a UISrollView and setting the scroll View frame to be what i want to display and making its content size large enough to hold the table inside it. It works perfectly fine. Now what i need to do is freeze the first column (that is not scroll it horizontally) but remaining table should horizontally.

I thought of doing this. Have a table view A and a UiScrollview containing a table view B aligned. And populate the first column data in table A and populate the remaining columns data in table B. This i feel should work for horizontal scrolling but then it wont have proper vertical scrolling as in the vertical scrolling wont be aligned. So the solution to this mite be to relatively scrolling table A vertically when table B is scrolled vertically and vice versa. But i am not how would i implement this. Any ideas.

Or is there an easier way of doing this.

Thanks
AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use two different tableviews. one inside scrollviw and the other outside it. then try using scrollview delegates to scroll through both tableviews simultaneously

Comment: It's not a good practice to put a tableView inside a scrollView.  Apple has been know to reject apps with this type of view arrangement.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method you can say something like 
    `if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
    //do not allow horizontal scrolling
    }
    else
    {
    //do allow it
    }`

Sorry for the pseudocode, I haven't seen your exact code so I can't comment on it myself, but that's the general idea.

Comment: Thanks for the response... But i guess I am not being very clear here. here is a scenario.
   c1   c2   c3
r1
r2
r3

Now what i want is to horizontally scroll c2 and c3 and not c1.
When I say indexpath.row it reflects to entire r1/r2/r3 which would contain the all three column elements c1,c2,c3.

Comment: I don't quite understand. You have a table of three rows and three columns made up of UITableViewCells?

Comment: Yes by each row is an instance of UITableview Cell which has 3 UiLabels in this case(columns here). Now i want to be able to scroll c2 and c3 horizontally and freeze c1. Also i would not want the individual cell to scroll horizontally, entire table needs to scroll. I know its very difficult to understand i just wish i cud draw it out.